# Will this sweep function work?

Tags: integration

I am currently working on implementing a frequency sweep function on a embedded device, and aren't sure that the math I am trying to implement actually does what I expect it to do.

The code I am trying to implement is  supposed to ramp up the signal from 0 hz to 48000 hz.

**The Math:**

Mathwise would a ramp be described as f(t) = a*t In which a is the slope and t is the time.

integrating f(t) gives F(t) which would be a function providing the time at which a cycle has been completed. such that if F = 1, then would t have the information of the period time of the cycle.

By reordering things I can get t(F) being a function that tells me at what time each cycle should be completed, which can be used to compute the next period time , and hence increase the frequency as it based on the ramp signal.

**Question:**
Is this correct, or I am misinterpreting something?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail on the problem?  You're trying to implement a function which plays a sound of increasing frequency from 0 to 48KHz, over some specified time, I guess.  But what functions can be used to implement that sound?

Comment: The problem is basically due to the use of the digital system, and that I won't be able to have a smooth transition between each frequency.

I need to know the intermediate frequency that provide a smooth transition between 0 and 48 khz within the timeframe of 10 sec.

Comment: If all you want is frequency vs. time, your $f$ function has it.  To find $a$, use the fact that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(10) = 48000$.  So $a=4800$ Hz/s.

Comment: I already have those information.. 

My question here is  my way of tackling the issue correct. Meaning t(F) function... does it do as i expect. or does it do something different.

Comment: I don't think you can get the period by integrating.  If you want the period, just invert the frequency.